# Rails 3.1 javascript_include_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'javascripts/admin/manage_customer.js' %>
   => <script src="/assets/javascripts/admin/manage_customer.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

How to generate simple JS link to `/javascripts/admin/manage_customer.js`in Rails 3.1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put a slash before that.

```
<%= javascript_include_tag '/javascripts/admin/manage_customer.js' %>
```